# VS 2019 - When I press the F5 button on the SQL Server Database Project I don't want to deploy to the database. I just want to build the project

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, database-versioning

I am currently working on database versioning project. And I'm using a SQL Server Database Project for this.

But we'll not use local database on the SSDT Project. Therefore I don't want to deployment when I press F5 button. I just want to build the project.

But the project configuration is not suitable for this. I cannot check deploy option. I'm looking for an alternative solution.

[Visual Studio 2019 sample project configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2npU.png)

Comment: Press CTRL-SHIFT-B instead of F5?

Comment: ctrl-shift-b doesnt work for table changes.  And we don't want to use local database so even a small change can adversely affect the entire database.